# Orthogonality and inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

The question relates to orthogonality and inner product spaces. If $ W,W_{1}, W_{2} $ are subspaces of finite dimensional vector space V. We have to prove the following

(a) $ W_{1} \subset W_{2}  \implies  W_{2}^\bot \subset W_{1}^\bot $

(b) $ (W_{1} + W_{2})^\bot = W_{1}^\bot \cap W_{2}^\bot $

(c) $ (W_{1} \cap W_{2})^\bot = W_{1}^\bot + W_{2}^\bot $

where $ W_{1}^\bot $ refers to the vector space orthogonal to $ W_{1} $

I have tried to solve the second part by the logic that $w\in W_{1} + W_{2} $ is expressed as

$$ w = w_{1} + w_{2} $$

where $ w_{1} \in W_{1} $ and  $ w_{2}  \in W_{2}$. A vector orthogonal to $w$ will exist in $ (W_{1} + W_{2})^\bot $ and let $ w^\bot $ be that vector.
But since 
$ w = w_{1} + w_{2} $, 
$ w^\bot $ is orthogonal to $ w_{1} $ and $ w_{2} $ also.
It implies that $ w^\bot $ element of $ W_{1}^\bot $  and $ W_{2}^\bot $ also. Hence $ w^\bot  \subset W_{1}^\bot \cap W_{2}^\bot $.

Please correct me if I'm wrong and kindly help out with the other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language makes things a little cumbersome, so let's try to avoid it as possible:

$$x\in\left(W_1+W_2\right)^\perp\iff \langle x,t\rangle=0\;,\;\forall\,t\in W_1+W_2\implies \forall\,w_i\in W_i\,,\,i=1,2\;:$$

$$0=\langle x,w_1+w_2\rangle\implies \;\text{choosing}\;\;w_2=0\;,\;\text{we get}\;\;\langle x,w_1\rangle=0\implies x\in W_1^\perp$$

and likewise $\,x\in W_2^\perp\;$ . The other direction is almost immediate (*almost*, though!)

Comment: @ Don Thanks. I tried the third part on similar lines. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Let $ w \in W_{1} \cap W_{2} $ and $ x \in W_{1}^\bot $ and $ y \in W_{2}^\bot $ langle x + y,w\rangle=0\;

Comment: @ Don Sorry didnt complete. I tried the third part on similar lines. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Let $ w \in W_{1} \cap W_{2} $ and $ x \in W_{1}^\bot $ and $ y \in W_{2}^\bot $. I tried to prove that  $\langle x + y,w\rangle=0\; \implies \langle x,w\rangle + $       $\langle y ,w\rangle=0\; $. Since w $ \in W_{1} and W_{2} $ x  is orthogonal to all vectors in $ W_{1}, so \langle x,w\rangle=0 $ and similarly we have $\langle$ $ y ,w\rangle=0\ $and hence the proof.

Comment: +1 Nice @Hashtag...but you still have to prove the other direction. :)

Comment: @ Don One more clarification please. If $\langle x+y,w \rangle = 0$ Does it mean vector space orthogonal to w is same as vector space of x + y?

Answer (score 3):

**(1)** Assume $W_1 \subset W_2$. Now, let

$$ w \in W_2^\bot \implies w \notin W_{2} \implies w \notin W_1 \implies w \in W_1^{\bot} \implies W_2^{\bot} \subset W_1^{\bot}.$$

**Note:**

> If $A\subset B$ and $x\in A$, then $x\in B$.

Comment: @ Mhenni Could you please clarify how $ w \notin W_{2} \implies w \notin W_1 $ . Shouldn't it be the other way around since $ W_1 \subset W_2$

Comment: @Hashtag: Because $W_1 \subset W_2$.

Comment: @ Mhenni I'm sorry for the terrible misinterpretation. I got your point.

Comment: @Hashtag: No problem.

Comment: @ Mhenni One more clarification please. Will $ w \notin W_1 $ $\implies w \in W_1^{\bot} $ always be the case irrespective of the number of dimensions of the vector space

Comment: @Hashtag: Yes, it is always the case.